# Verificar arquivos que possuem determinada palavra - Python (Biblioteca os)

Tags: python

Tenho o código abaixo ao qual eu acesso uma determinada pasta e trago o nome de todos os arquivos com extensão .asp.

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir('G:\PASTA\SUBPASTA')
for file in glob.glob('*.asp'):
    print(file)
```

Preciso melhorar esse código da seguinte forma:

Acessar arquivo por arquivo contido na pasta e identificar quais arquivos possuem uma determinada palavra dentro dele.

Exemplo:

Quais arquivos possuem a palavra *bench* e em seguida trazer a lista encontrada, tal como:

```
G:\PASTA\SUBPASTA\Arquivo.asp

G:\PASTA\SUBPASTA\ArquivoXPTO.asp
```

Comment: Sabe ler o conteúdo de um arquivo?

Comment: Ainda não Anderson.

Comment: Então comece pesquisando sobre a função `open` e a biblioteca `io` nativa do Python.

Comment: import glob 
import os

arq = os.chdir('G:\PANALYTICS\_PROD\IAMData-u\Pesquant_C\SiteSSG\Fundo')
for file in glob.glob('*.asp'):
    for info in open(file):
        #if info.read().contenha_a_palavra('bench'):
            #print(file)

Comment: Anderson, acredito que esse seja o caminho. Não consegui evoluir a questão de identificar a palavra dentro do arquivo

Comment: `if 'bench' in info.read()` já resolveria, mas deixo você estudar melhor a biblioteca para analisar a solução. Boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson. Vou criar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa abrir o conteúdo do arquivo primeiramente e depois realizar uma leitura verificando se a palavra deseja está dentro do arquivo.

## Como abrir arquivo em Python ?

Para abrir um arquivo em Python utilize a função `open()`.
Nessa função você deverá passar o caminho do arquivo (só é necessário o nome caso o arquivo esteja no mesmo diretório do seu programa ) e o modo de abertura.

## Como ler arquivos em Python ?

Após abrir o arquivo você precisará ler o conteúdo. Para isso existem três métodos que você pode usar: `read()`, `readline()` e `readlines()`.
No seu caso, eu recomendo utilizar o `read()` para agilizar tudo.

## Fechando o arquivo.

Depois de abrir e fazer a leitura do arquivo, você deverá fechá-lo utilizando o método `close()`. Após utilizar este método, você não poderá mais acessar o conteúdo deste arquivo até que o mesmo seja aberto novamente.

## Como ficaria meu código após isso tudo ?

```
import glob
import os

key = "<Digite a palavra aqui>"

os.chdir('G:\PASTA\SUBPASTA')
for filename in glob.glob('*.asp'):
    print("Verificando o arquivo",filename,"...")
    file = open(filename)
    if key in file.read():
        print("A palavra",key,"existe no arquivo",filename+"!")
    file.close()
```

Eu recomendo que você estude mais sobre o `open()`, pois existem muito mais coisas nele que podem ser úteis para você.

Comment: #Com as dicas e escrevi a seguinte função

Comment: import glob
import os

def proc_term_dir(diret, ext, termo):
    """
        retorna o nome dos arquivos que possuem um determinado termo
    """
    caminho = os.chdir(diret)
    for file in glob.glob(ext):
        for info in open(file, encoding='utf8'):
            if termo in info:
                print(file)

Comment: Perfeito! Você apenas esqueceu de fechar o arquivo, mas tudo bem kkk. O importante é você ter entendido a como usar o open =D